# What is the syntax for including model properties in a Html.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

For example say I have the following code inside a foreach to generate a table. In one of the columns there is a "Click here to view more details" type link. The PurchaseOrderNumber should create a hyperlink that points to a Details page and pass in the PurchaseOrderNumber. Example: /Sales/Details/7000

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Index", @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.PurchaseOrderNumber))
    </td>
```

Instead it is only creating hyperlinks to /Sales?Length=5

How do I correctly do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your controller name is `Sales`, action name is `Details` and the parameter name is `id`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here for more details",
                 "Details",
                 "Sales",
                 new { id = item.PurchaseOrderNumber }, null)
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: That's still generating the same URL's as before for me

Comment: What is the name of the controller, the action and the parameter name?

Comment: Exactly as you have them in your code, but it's just creating "Length=5" whatever that means.

Comment: Wrong overload - you need to add a 5th parameter for the html attributes - `@Html.ActionLink("Click here for more details", "Details", "Sales", new { id = item.PurchaseOrderNumber }, null)`